# pull/clone statistics with Gitolite

Tags: git, repository, gitolite

I am using **gitolite** for managing a repository and I want to know who accessed to the last changes and when. Is it possible to retrieve information of pull/clone requests from a remote when using **gitolite** for managing the repos? Is there any records of these operations? What about it if I use other tools and not gitolite?

Thanks in advance.

(I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697557/is-there-a-way-to-get-download-clone-statistics-of-a-git-repository/6699109#6699109) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778786/administration-of-git-server-track-the-process-of-repository-cloning?lq=1)  but mine seems more specific since I'm asking about gitolite or similar tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the files maintained in `~/.gitolite/logs` [by gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/files.html).

Those log files will record any git operation, authorized or denied.

But they aren't "exported" or visible outside the gitolite server by default.
To expose them, you need some kind of audit log web server, like for instance **[`logstash`](http://logstash.net/)** (which is a generic tool, for managing events and logs: it isn't linked to gitolite, but can parse its logs and display information about their content).